# Create div with a specific coordinate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

**HTML:**

```
<div id="textDiv">
    <input type="text" id="txt" value="Add TextBox" style="" readonly /><br>
</div>
<div id="holder"></div>
```

There are 2 `div`. Using jQuery UI a new `div` is created in `div` with `id="holder"`.

In the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textDiv").draggable({
        helper: 'clone',
    });
    $("#holder").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Div' + inputs.length);
            newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
                '<label id="textLabel' + inputs.length + '">TextboxLabel #' + i + ' : </label>
                <input type="text" name="textbox' + inputs.length + '" id="text' + inputs.length + '" value="" placeholder="textbox #' + i + '" checked="" >
                <input type="button" onclick="xtext(\'' + inputs.length + '\')" id="xtext' + inputs.length + '" value="x">
                <input type="button" onclick="edittext(\'' + inputs.length + '\')"  id="edittext' + inputs.length + '" value="edit">');
                newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#holder");
            i++;
        }
```

How can I insert the new `div` where the mouse is stopped when dropping the clone?

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the div center along X and Y axis like this -

```
#elem{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:50px;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
```

Or with JavaScript:

```
var d = document.getElementById('yourDivId');
d.style.position = "absolute";
d.style.left = x_pos;
d.style.top = y_pos;
```

Comment: but the x and y i want them the same coordinate as the coordinate of the clone

Comment: $( "#1" ).draggable({
 helper:'clone',
 cancel:false,
 stop: handleDragStop
 });

Comment: function handleDragStop( event, ui ) {
  var offsetXPos = parseInt( ui.offset.left );
  var offsetYPos = parseInt( ui.offset.top );